# How to fix the errors Can not read property push of null with the exportmenu.draw of amcharts4?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

In one page we are loading amcharts4 mapcharts, line charts and pie charts and  with heavy data.
When the onload of a page map charts are not loading properly and in the browsers console it is throwing bunch of console errors.

Here the errors

```
zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at ExportMenu.push../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/export/ExportMenu.js.ExportMenu.draw (ExportMenu.js:209)
    at ExportMenu.push../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/export/ExportMenu.js.ExportMenu.validate (ExportMenu.js:171)
    at Object.dispatch (EventDispatcher.js:381)
    at EventDispatcher.js:266
    at Module.each (Array.js:74)
    at EventDispatcher.push../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/utils/EventDispatcher.js.EventDispatcher._eachListener (EventDispatcher.js:239)
    at EventDispatcher.push../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/utils/EventDispatcher.js.EventDispatcher.dispatchImmediately (EventDispatcher.js:264)
    at Registry.push../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/Registry.js.Registry.dispatchImmediately (Registry.js:209)
    at System.push../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/System.js.System.update (System.js:299)
    at System.js:343
```

When we tried commenting out the below lines in charts components it is not throwing errors but loose the export functionality

```
if (chartConfig.export && chartConfig.export.enabled) {
      newChart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
      newChart.exporting.menu.verticalAlign = chartConfig.export.valign as am4core.VerticalCenter;
      newChart.exporting.menu.align = chartConfig.export.halign as am4core.Align;
}
```

so what causing these errors and how can i fix these errors, and keeping export functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I had same error till amCharts 4 version 4.7.5 , after I updated to version 4.7.12 as of writing this answer the issue was solved.

My suggestion is that you upgrade your package.json file with the latest version of amCharts i.e. 4.7.12 for now as of 5 December, 2019 which will solve your issue.